# Increasing The Momentum Of A Photon

Tags: energy, photons, momentum

Is there another way to increase a photon's momentum other than increasing its energy?

Comment: If the laws of physics were different, what would they be like? It is a little difficult to answer this type of question.

Comment: @mmesser314 I think it is a trivial question to answer. The OP is simply asking can we increase the momentum without increasing energy. The answer would be simply no.

Comment: @Dvij, I quote from the original version of the post the question that prompted mmesser314's comment:  *"IF! a photon could go faster than the speed of light, would its momentum increase?"*

Comment: @AlfredCentauri Okay, I remember and realize the issue. My bad.

Comment: @Dafeet - This question got quite a few down votes and votes to close, but it isn't such a bad question. Many people ask questions like what if you could go the speed of light, and similar. I hope you are not put off by this. Our site can overdo it sometimes.

Comment: Discussion on meta: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9989/25301

Comment: Please can you explain what difficulty you are having with this question. Why do you think there might be *another way*?

Comment: Ok, I'm new to this whole stack exchange thing and I had a question in my mind that i admit, was a pretty bad question, but then i decided to edit the question so that it wouldnt be down voted any more or recieve any more negative comments. So all I'm asking of you guys is to cut me some slack.

Answer (score 4):

A photon can never go at a speed greater than the speed of light. The laws of Special Relativity dictate that it must go precisely at the speed of light. The momentum of a photon is also related to its energy by the relation $E=pc$ as dictated by Special Relativity and thus, its momentum can not be changed without changing its energy.

**Explanation**

Special Relativity tells us that the energy and momentum of a particle are given by the following relations:  $$E=\dfrac{mc^2}{\sqrt{1-\dfrac{v^2}{c^2}}}$$

$$p=\dfrac{mv}{\sqrt{1-\dfrac{v^2}{c^2}}}$$
Now, as one can see, for a particle with $m=0$ (such as a photon), the only way to have a finite energy/momentum is to go at $v=c$.

Special Relativity also tells us that the following relation always holds for a particle of mass $m$: $$E^2-p^2c^2=m^2c^4$$
So, as one can easily see, for a particle like photon whose $m=0$, $E=pc$ and thus, without increasing the energy, one can't increase its momentum.

Comment: "Special Relativity _also_ tells us that the following relation always holds for a particle of mass m." This need not be the case because $E^2 - {p^2}{c^2} = {m^2}{c^4}$ follows from the relations $$E=\frac{m{c^{2}}}{\sqrt{1-{\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}}$$ and $$p=\frac{mv}{\sqrt{1-{\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}}$$

Comment: @PhyEnthusiast Not quite. Individual formulae for $E$ and $p$ actually break down for $v=c$ and $m=0$. Yes, we can say that $v=c$ should be accompanied with $m=0$ but other than that, it fails to produce any quantitative results. While $E^2-p^2c^2=m^2c^4$ holds generically without any complications.

Comment: So, in a purist's sense, $E^2-p^2=m^2$ is a stronger statement than the individual formulae for $E$ and $p$ as they simply not cover the case of $v=1$. In physics, we usually expect continuity and we can take the limit of $E/p$ from their individual formula for the case of $v$ tending to $1$ - so as you said, one can scrap by with the individual formulae. But given sufficient time and resources, I would like to be explicit and purer. ;-)

Comment: Ok, so is it the case that the individual formulae for $E$ and $p$ and the relation $E^2−p^2 c^2=m^2 c^4$; all three can be derived independent of each other from special relativity??

Comment: [Am asking this question here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/344679/how-are-these-derived-e-fracmc2-sqrt1-fracv2c2-p-fracm). Please care to answer.